# How to autosize label like this InterfaceBuilder Settings?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, width, uilabel, autosize

i want to set the autosize settings for an uilabel programmatically.
i want exactly the same settings like in the interface builder settings i set, see here:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/545/bildschirmfoto20120508u.png/

so how can i set it programmatically? i want full width.

i have tried it with:

```
titleLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

But when i use this, my label is very strange (in portraitmode is the width 0 and in landscape approx 100).

so how to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I see you want full width, but flexible bottom, so you should use this autoresizing mask value:

```
titleLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
```

Comment: i have done it without the top margin and it works, thank you: **titleLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;**